# Slow down a loop doing only certain number of iteration per second

Tags: r

it might be sound a little bit strange but is there somwhow a possibility to slowdown a loop in R? For example to let R do only one iteration per second.

Thank you

Comment: add `Sys.sleep(1)` at the end of the loop. It will wait one second before the next iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this line inside your loop:

```
Sys.sleep(1)
```

That will slow done each iteration in the loop for 1 second.